# Tool for custom color scheme for bing maps or openlayers

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-3, bing-maps

After some research i couldn't find a tool like snazzy maps for maps provided by bing or openlayers. Does anyone know such a tool?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps currently does not support custom map styles, however this is on the feature request as a possible future feature.